# Can a system app be updated?

Tags: android, google-play

If i have a system app on an Android with the same package signature and that has a new version on the Android Market will the Market detect it and be able to update it?

(For example an app that a Carrier adds to the OS).

**UPDATE:** 
Managed to validate this anwswer (marked it as resolved already)...but a new one appeared: [Why doesnt the market show the system app on "my apps" when an update is available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7834160/why-doesnt-the-market-show-the-system-app-on-my-apps-when-an-update-is-availab))

Comment: You *really* want to ask this question of the device manufacturer and/or carrier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: Yes.

After you install them, you will have the option of "uninstall updates" instead of "uninstall" as you see for the regular apps.

However, most carrier apps don't have updates through market, only google apps do. (For example: Gmail updates fairly often while SpringID may never update because they are not on the market)

Comment: On older versions of Android i had Gmail pre-installed but market didn't offered me updates for it.. neither i could find it if i searched Gmail on the market.. why is that? It was on a HTC Hero GSM

Comment: What version is your Hero running on? You probably have the latest version that is available for your firmware. Some of the new updates only applies to Gingerbread or later Android phones.

Comment: However, you can try getting a standalone version from http://www.xda-developers.com/ or use Cyangenmod (Gingerbread) ROM.

Comment: Hum.. i was using 2.1 at the time (some months ago).

Comment: That's probably why. Many of the Gmail updates in the past half year were only issued to Android 2.2 and up. (Android is now 4.0, and we are not even sure if 2.3 will get the new Gmail look from 4.0....). If you switch to Cyangenmod though you should be able to enjoy the latest google apps.

Comment: Yeah now i have Cyangenmod. But i wanted to known if there was any other "limiter" on the update because of an app being on the system folder, and by that, no being writeble without root or something like that.

Comment: I see. There is no limiter for apps that are in the system folder.